# ajax POST calling not working in IE but is in all other browsers

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jquery, post

Hey all i have the following ajax POST call:

```
function callAjax(what2Do)
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "count.php?do=" + what2Do,
            type: "POST",
            data: "",
            cache: false,
            success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                alert('done!');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(
                    "The following error occured: "+
                    textStatus, errorThrown
                );
            }
        });
    }
```

And i keep getting the error **The following error occured: error** when running the page in iE9 but it works just fine in all other browsers.

What would i be missing to not have it work in IE? The return is simple text.

Comment: To get better information, fix the alert so that you get more information. `textStatus + "|" + errorThrown`

Comment: Check out the network tab in IE9 dev tools (F12). This should give you the full response. If you stuggle after that, post the response here for further help.

Comment: My money is on him meaning IE8.

Comment: @flem: In the response body in the network tab it has the correct value of **NOTLIKED** and its sending the parameter just fine as well so i'm not sure why its erroring out?

Comment: @KevinB: The error is **TypeError: Object doesnt support property or method 'toLowerCase'** I am running this inside facebook tab.

Comment: Post the code where you are calling toLowerCase. If you aren't, I would take a look at my code below because I think the problem might be something jQuery is doing to your POST/GET vars that IE is not cool with. You really shouldn't be submitting GET vars through the QString and sending empty POST content anyway.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson: Yeah im not calling any type of toLowerCase.

Comment: Hmm. What version of jQuery are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately had to do a crash course in legacy IE behavior to deal with almost identical conditions.  In my case it came down to a stubborn [insistence](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-appformats/2008Mar/0021.html) of IE to use their own proprietary XDomainRequest object to handle CORS.  Some good links:

- [A great overview of the situation and some ways to address the associated problems](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/11-10-03/using_cors_with_all_modern_browsers.aspx)
- [Microsoft's Documentation of their XDomainRequest object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [An internal MS blog post covering some of XDomainRequest's idiosyncrasies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx)

As distasteful as it is to make exceptions for browsers that refuse to follow standards, I use something like the following in my projects to account for the situation where necessary:

```
// This is necessary due to IE<10 having no support for CORS.
function fallbackXDR(callObj) {
    if (window.XDomainRequest) { 
        var xdrObj = new XDomainRequest();
        xdrObj.timeout = callObj.timeout;
        xdrObj.onload = function() {
            handleSuccess(xdrObj.responseText);
        };
        xdrObj.onerror = function() {
            handleError(xdrObj);
        };
        xdrObj.ontimeout = function() {
            callObj.xdrAttempts = callObj.xdrAttempts++ || 1;
            if (callObj.xdrAttempts < callObj.maxAttempts) {
                fallbackXDR(callObj);
            }
        };
        xdrObj.onprogress = function() {
            // Unfortunately this has to be included or it will not work in some cases.
        };

        // Use something other than $.param() to format the url if not using jQuery.
        var callStr = callObj ? '?'+$.param(callObj.urlVars) : '';
        xdrObj.open("get", callObj.url+callStr);
        xdrObj.send();
    } else {
        handleError("No XDomainRequest available.", callObj);
    }
}//fallbackXDR()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function callAjax(what2Do)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "./count.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'do': what2Do },
        cache: false,
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('done!');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(
                "The following error occured: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Second that suggestion. Also remember to modify the server-side code to use the POST data instead of GET data

Comment: Yeah, that was my concern was that OP was sending a POST with GET data in the URL. Shouldn't be a problem, but IE8 especially is very finicky about stuff like that.

Comment: Can you please try to place this right before the jQuery.ajax( line?

alert(what2Do);